# True or false - can an input type="button" element be coded as disabled?

Tags: php, html, button

I have two groups of two buttons (input type="button). One or both buttons in a group can be enabled at a time but the groups are mutually exclusion - only one group will have enabled buttons at any time.

I want to enable or disable the buttons as they are created in my PHP code, based, of course, on certain criteria. I could use JavaScript, after the fact, on the client, but that seems like doing something in the most round about way you can find. Using one "language" to make up for another language's deficiencies and something that is documented as being possible with HTML, is absurd.

It varies a bit, but the documentation I've found all about the web says that you should be able to disable a button when the tag is created.

Some places say that putting disabled on the tag will disable the button. Others hint at needing to specify disabled=something - there's not really any agreement on what the "something" should be. Here is an example of one of my input tags:

```
<input type="button" value="Next Post">
```

The enabled buttons will be wrapped in a <a> tag

I've tried:

```
disabled
disabled=""
disabled="true"
disabled="yes"
disabled="disabled
```

I know how to disable the button via JavaScript but it seems to be going to extremes to do something that is documented as doable on the tag definition.

Is there a way to disable the input type="button" in the tag specification, and if so, how?

Comment: I copied the example given in one of the answers and the button does not show as disabled. I used   echo '<input type="button" disabled="disabled" value="Next Post">'; The button looks exactly like one next to it which does not have disabled="disabled"  If I click on the "disabled" button, it acts like a button, it changes to "drepressed" style. I tried <button type="button" disabled>Click Me!</button> as given in another answer, still not disabled. I would not think it germane to the issue, but the code in question is in a Wordpress Theme functions file. Could WP be doing somthing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had to dig and find it myself. My thought about Wordpress causing the problems (in the comment I posted to my question) got me to thinking about that and I decided to start wading through a huge css file with dozens of rules and elements which apply to input, button, etc. tags.

I started with the sledgehammer and replaced the file with an empty file. That did it, the buttons now show as disabled.

I wish someone had thought of that possibility before I spend additional time trying various modifications on the input tags.

I will not go dig into the css, rule and element at a time, to find just what is causing the buttons to not be disabled - at least as regards appearance and "click ability".

To whoever voted my question down, sorry that it did not meet your standards for questions.

In the teaching I've done, a lot of it, mostly technical, both credit and noncredit courses and to computer professional on new systems software or features in upgraded software, I learned, early on, that there is only one type of stupid question - the question someone has but doesn't ask.

But I guess most people have never hit upon that bit of wisdom. It has has been quite beneficial when I'm teaching or helping someone and I'm glad I learned it.

Oh, if you haven't guessed, I'm one of those mainframers and all I know is terribly obsolete in the PC world.

I'm sorry if my question appeared to be stupid, at least to someone - it wasn't stupid for me. I had fought with those tags for a very long time and had gotten no where. So, for me, it wasn't a stupid question. It was very germane to what I'm working, on the side.

Sorry for the rant.

When I find out just what is causing my problem, I'll come back here and post some comments about.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go

```
<button type="button" disabled>Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" disabled="disabled" value="Next Post">
```

This seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you think adding a `disabled` attribute to the input doesn't work, exactly. It should work just fine.

```html
<input type="button" value="Next Post" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add that **disabled** tag.

```
<input type = "button" value = "Button" disabled />
```